# Getting this error when trying to run windows 8 samples The type or namespace name 'WindowCreatedEventArgs' could not be found?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

i was trying to use windows 8 samples provided by Microsoft , i have no idea why i am getting this error , it says :-

**Error1 The type or namespace name 'WindowCreatedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?**

Please let me know how can i resolve this problem

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: which sample are you trying to run?  Windows.UI.Xaml needs to be in your "using" section, but if it's not you'll likely be getting more errors than just that one.